# Getting value from a PHP array converted from json

Tags: php, arrays

Here is the var_export of $myArray:

```
Array:array (  '@attributes' => 
  array (  'success' => 'true',  ),   'Client' => '1218421234', )
```

What is the code to get the value of Client into a string??  I tried several constructs but must be having a 'senior' day...

Obviously,

```
$client = $myArray->Client;
```

...did not work, neither did...

```
$client = $myArray->attributes()->Client;
```

... any help?

Comment: $myArray['Client']

Answer (score 3):

It's an array, so you should access to it as:

```
$myArray['Client']
```

As `$myArray->Client` would be if `$myArray` was an object and `Client` a property of that object and the same goes for `@attributes` which is just another array with the key 'success'.

Answer (score 2):

The result you have shown indicates that `'Client'` is a `String` inside an `array`, so it's `$myArray['Client']`.

Both your first and second try assumes that `$myArray` is not an `array`.